# Refactoring class that only store constant value and pure function?

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring, abstraction

Initially I have some class with similar structure that store some variable. After create abstract class and refactoring few times, instance variable is pulled out (only class constant left) and method become pure function. I have gut feeling that I did it wrong and  still need refactoring. I create this example below to illustrate what I end up with. Am I really misunderstood object oriented abstraction and apply it wrong? How can I refactor it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

abstract class Subject{
    abstract public string Name{ get; }
    abstract public int Credit { get; }
    abstract public Subject getNextRequiredCourse(List<Subject> learnedCourses);
    
    protected static Subject getMissingCourse(List<Subject> required, List<Subject> learnedCourses){
        foreach(var x in required){
             var temp = x.getNextRequiredCourse(learnedCourses);
             if (temp != null){
                 return temp;
             }
             bool match = false;
             foreach(var y in learnedCourses){
                if (x.Name == y.Name){ match = true; break; }   
             }
             if (!match){ return x;}
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class CalculusI : Subject{
    public override string Name { get => "MTH101";}
    public override int Credit { get => 3;}
    public override Subject getNextRequiredCourse(List<Subject> learnedCourses){
        return null;
    }
}

class Algebra : Subject{
    public override string Name { get => "MTH201";}
    public override int Credit { get => 3;}
    public override Subject getNextRequiredCourse(List<Subject> learnedCourses){
        return null;
    }
}

class CalculusII : Subject{
    public override string Name { get => "MTH102";}
    public override int Credit { get => 3;}
    public override Subject getNextRequiredCourse(List<Subject> learnedCourses){
        List<Subject> required = new List<Subject>(){new CalculusI()};
        return CalculusII.getMissingCourse(required, learnedCourses);
    }
}

class CalculusIII : Subject{
    public override string Name { get => "MTH103";}
    public override int Credit { get => 3;}
     public override Subject getNextRequiredCourse(List<Subject> learnedCourses){
        List<Subject> required = new List<Subject>(){new CalculusII()};
        return CalculusIII.getMissingCourse(required, learnedCourses);
    }
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var learned = new List<Subject>(){ new Algebra()};
        
        var next = new CalculusIII().getNextRequiredCourse(learned);
        if (next != null){
            Console.WriteLine (next.Name);
        }
        else{ Console.WriteLine ("Hello World");}
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

Note: The example above is just simplified runnable example. Functions only have same signature

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong about this approach. If you don't add members in the deriving classes, another option is to use the factory pattern. You will also need to add information about the next required course.

Roughly sketched:

```cs
public static class SubjectFactory
{
    // Assuming an appropriate constructor.
    public static Subject CreateCalculusI() =>
        new Subject("MTH101", 3, null);

    public static Subject CreateAlgebra() =>
        new Subject("MTH201", 3, null);

    public static Subject CreateCalculusII() =>
        new Subject("MTH102", 3, CreateCalculusI());

    public static Subject CreateCalculusIII() =>
        new Subject("MTH103", 3, CreateCalculusII());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you didn't miss anything. This can happen. Keep exploring the possible designs and see which are overtly complicated and which describe the problem at hand in it's most simple terms and are easy to extend when new functionality is required.

First a question, do you need all subjects to be their own class? And if so, does the singleton pattern make sense? For example all instances of the CalculusII class behave exactly the same and are not modifiable. So why create a new instance that does the same as all other instances. It also makes equality comparison easier.

If not so, is subject just a data object? Containing the name, credit and required courses. This is a more data oriented approach where the subject class is more dumb and the 'smart' code is pushed elsewhere. If you eventually want to place these in a database this might be better, You can't put classes in a database, only objects with only data.

The 'learnedCourses' parameter is now passed around in the implementation classes. It seems this can be moved to the Subject class. Make a

```
abstract protected List<Subject> getRequiredCourses();
```

method that is implemented in the implementations. Make it do very little and put all the complicated parts in the Subject class. The **getNextRequiredCourse()** method can be implemented directly in the Subject class and loop though the required courses. It means that to understand the algorithm you only have to look in this place as the **getRequiredCourses()** becomes trivial and just does what its name implies.

It sometimes helps to write algorithms first as one big ugly function and then later split of parts that deserve to have their own name. Like **getMissingCourse()**. It might be split out, it might not be. Only spread functionality around if the separate parts can be used on their own and make sense on their own. In this case I think they are so dependent conceptually that I'd like to have them close to each other in the same class.

Keep code that changes together together and place code with non important details elsewhere. Right now I need to look at every implementation of **getNextRequiredCourse()** to see what it does and to understand why **getMissingCourse()** is even there. If you switch it up a bit, it becomes easier to understand and saves yourself some WTF moments later when you have to change it. ;)

This is meant as constructive criticism. And my opinion is just that, an opinion.

Comment: I do not know if using Singleton with interface is better or worse than this approach? I forget to show that override function may or may not share any logic at all. Look like my example mislead you from the main point of question (class with const and pure function). You can think of it similar to Object class with ToString() method but derived Object only have const data and ToString() have parameters. I also think of using Enum, Dictionary<Enum, Tuple> and Singleton but to change things at 3 places is too bothersome

Comment: Then, I think I misunderstood the situation. (And it is not clearer to me now) :( So just in general: there is no single right pattern in most real world cases. It is all trade offs. I usually ask myself the question: If I need to come back at this to make a small change, how easy is it to find where I need to make the change and how confident am I, not breaking something? In other words code readability.
Also no code is perfect, and I think you'll get this right.

Comment: Code readability... that is really a good points. Initially class I make do have some instance members but it is a duplicated data from somewhere else (more important) and get invalid when data at that place change. The question that you asked yourself is really helpful to me.